# XMLDecoder.readObject() returns null

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to read an object from a XML file using XMLDecoder.
The construction seems to be OK, but when I call the readObject() method i get null instead of the object I expected.

The file exists and the created BufferedInputStream reads the file correctly.
This code works OK on the original Vista laptop it was written on, but fails on my Win Xp machine.

```
     try {
        XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(new BufferedInputStream(
            new FileInputStream("Params.xml")));

        Params = (Parameters)decoder.readObject();
        decoder.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString()); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the same version of Java being used on the Vista and XP boxes?
Also check the version of Java used to create the xml originally.

Another test would be to encode an object on the XP box and try and read it back.

Comment: It's been a while:) Eventually i did just that, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If it fails on your XP machine, but works on your Vista machine, then that sounds like some environment problem.

As it involves XML, I wonder if there's a character encoding issue and your Vista/XP environments have different encoding properties set. If this is the case then the XMLDecoder may not be able to parse the XML properly.

Check your system property `file.encoding` on both installations. It would be interesting to see if they're different. Does your .xml file specify the character encoding ?

Comment: the XML file specifies UTF-8 encoding.

You were right about file.encoding not matching, I can't check the Vista machine right now 
but I don't think it matches.

I've set file.encoding to UTF-8 on my machine and tried converting it to UTF-8 (with and without BOM), the decoded object is still null.

Comment: If the XML file specifies an encoding, then the VM encoding shouldn't matter

Answer (score 0):

That means that somehow your `InputStream` is considered 'empty' by the `XmlDecoder`.

Could you try:

```
XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(new FileInputStream("Params.xml"));
```

using directly `FileInputStream` instead of `BufferedInputStream` ?

Or try to `reset()` your `BufferedInputStream` before using it in your `XmlEncoder` initialization ?

Comment: Just tried it with FileInputStream directly, the returned object is still null

Answer (score 0):

You could try constructing your `XMLDecoder` with a custom `ExceptionListener` and put a `println` in it.

```
public XMLDecoder(InputStream in,
                  Object owner,
                  ExceptionListener exceptionListener)
```

Also, `readObject` throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the stream contains no objects (or no more objects), are you catching that exception ?

Comment: I can trigger the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if I call readObject() the second time. So *something* is read the first time.